# What is the default behavior of the odometry display in Rviz?

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am wondering what is the default behaviour I should expect from the odomety display we have in Rviz.

More precisely, I wonder if the odometry arrows should follow the twist information:

- Should the arrow point toward where the robot is going? I mean, when the robot drives backward, should the arrows point toward its back or is it normal that they stay oriented toward its front?
- Should the arrow's length be proportional with the instant velocities carried in the twist section of the odometry message?

Thanks in advance

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9741/what-is-the-default-behavior-of-the-odometry-display-in-rviz?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the odometry visualization in rviz simply allows for visualization of the pose contained in the the nav_msgs/Odometry message. I don't think it does anything with the geometry_msgs/Twist, though that would be a useful feature request for rviz. So, you'd expect the arrow to stay the same size and simply convey the robot's position in the odometric frame at a given point. More information on how rviz treats odometry messages can be found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Odometry

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-04-15**:
Thanks eitan. I did check the doc before posting my question, but the video only shows the pr2 moving forward :) indeed, having odom follow the twist info could be a nice feature.